# How to construct a Python object that has an underlying non-contiguous buffer (as obtained by `PyObject_GetBuffer`)?

Tags: python, python-c-api

The Python C API includes a function, `PyBuffer_IsContiguous` for verifying if the returned buffer is contiguous.

How to construct an object such as that function returns a false value?

Here are a few examples that do not work (all tried with Python 3.10):

```py
a = b"123"
b = b"456"
c = bytearray(a[0:1] + b[0:1])
# This one returns a contiguous buffer even if id(b[0]) == id(c[1])
# Who does the copying? Why? Any rules?
```

```py
np.zeros((2, 3)).T
# PyObject_GetBuffer fails instead of returning a strided array
```

```py
memoryview(b"123")[::2]
# PyObject_GetBuffer fails instead of returning a strided array
```

Comment: Your bottom two should work. BUt it'll depend on what flags you pass to PyObject_GetBuffer (which you don't show).

Comment: `PyBUF_STRIDES` achieves the desired effect, you can answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> c = bytearray(a[0:1] + b[0:1])
> # This one returns a contiguous buffer even if id(b[0]) == id(c[1])
> # Who does the copying? Why? Any rules?
> ```

There are actually many different copied copies. `a[0:1]` and `b[0:1]` return new (i.e. copied) `bytes` objects, not views on the existing `bytes` objects. `... + ...` also returns a new `bytes` object containing the combined contents. `bytearray` then also returns a new `bytearray` object with its own internal memory store.

`id(b[0]) == id(c[1])` tells you nothing - `b[0]` and `c[1]` return a reference to a Python `int`. That Python `int` *does not share* memory with the `bytes` object that generated it. What you're seeing is the results of an optimization - Python keep a cache of small ints and returns a reference to an object from that cache rather than creating a new one. So you get multiple references to the same `int`.

---

Your other two suggestions are non-contiguous arrays. As suggested in the comments: `PyObject_GetBuffer` has a flags variable that controls what type of buffer it can return (and it'll raise an error it can't produce the right type of buffer). [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#shape-strides-suboffsets) has three tables detailing the various flags, but largely anything with `strides` marked as "YES" should be able to handle a non-contiguous array. Your suggestion (in the comments) of `PyBUF_STRIDES` is probably the simplest thing that will.